# Reading CSV file and manipulating the components (a newbie question)

Tags: pandas, csv, matrix

So, I have just started learning python. I am trying to read a .csv file (https://www.dropbox.com/s/fp1g32uv2cljd1n/adcpDat.csv?dl=0)
in python.

I can read in the file but then when I want to choose one of the components it returns Traceback (most recent call last) error.

```
import os
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


os.chdir("/Users/K1/Documents/Work/UGA/Cruise/GC600-MP/Data/ADCP/")
print("Current Working Directory ", os.getcwd())

adcpDat = pd.read_csv("adcpDat.csv")
print(adcpDat.shape)
```

output is

```
Current Working Directory  /Users/K1/Documents/Work/UGA/Cruise/GC600-MP/Data/ADCP
(805945, 1)
```

but when I run for example,

```
adcpDat[3]
```

it just returns an error.

How can I pick the components?

Answer (score 0):

You first have to specify the column name, then the row number:

```
adcpDat['rowname'][3]
```

In the case of your csv file it would be:

```
adcpDat['tADCP'][3]
```

This is because the first line of the csv file specifies the row name which is `tADCP`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot!